# Ubuntu 11.04 server crash report

Tags: log-files, ubuntu-11.04, server-crashes

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 server addition for my application. During some testing my server has just crashed. After that I am restart the server. My problem is how can i find the reason of crashing? I have googled it and find some suggesstion of checking /var/log/syslog but its too big file. how can i track the reason of crashing?

Comment: You need to look for kernel ops/bugs/segfaults or any other error/warning. Maybe, you can filter the irrelevant parts using `grep -v` gradually until you get a reasonably-sized file.

Comment: Thanks Khaled. But the information you have given is not avaiblable in machine. there is no such directory of opt in my ubuntu server editions.

Answer (score 1):

The recommendations are right:

```
/var/log/syslog
/var/log/messages
```

When you say it is "too big file" - what exactly do you mean?  Sometimes you need to plod through giant log files to figure out what went wrong.  That's the life of a system administrator...

Comment: also, you can use `dmesg` to see what occurred in the kernel logs.

Comment: "too big" means there is too many lines in that file. and i also dont know which message indicates crash of system.

Comment: It's going to be hard to find what you are looking for without digging in.  Troubleshooting is an art and you need to just read through the logs.  I suggest trying to replicate the crash and then immediately reviewing the logs after to reboot to look for anything anomalous.